# pdfmake - How can i get pdf generate time?

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I'm using [PDFMake](http://pdfmake.org) to generate a PDF in client side. Can I get the PDF generation time to show the user how long is left to wait?

Comment: Don't think so. Alternatively, if you use getDataUrl(..) you can show a spinner until the callback is resolved ...

Comment: @AardVark71, if you look at the [playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html), you will see that there is a "time to generate field on that page, so it must be possible.

Comment: @doveyg yes, they do show a "generate***d*** in ...ms" but please note thats generateD and not generate (Past <> Present). So also here they don't show _how long is left to wait_ (like the OP asked). Yes, you can indicate AFTER the pdf is generated how long it took, in the same way a spinner can be shown to indicate the pdf is generating [using the getDataurl(...) callback ]

Answer (score -1):

After a Google lookup, **I don't think that PdfMake has such a feature.**

**As a workaround**, you can maybe run pdfmake using `console.time()` with various quantity of content to print, to know what the shortest and longest export times are. By doing so, you can then guess how long will the next pdf take to export based on the quantity of input data.

Example:

```
- shortestExportTime (300 chars long text) is 30 sec
- longestExportTime (900 chars long text) is 2 min

=> Current text to export is 600 chars long, estimated 1min 15
```